# TABLE1 T1, TABLE2 T2 WHERE T1.Blah = T2.Blah - VS - INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Provided that the tables could essentially be inner joined, since the where clause excludes all records that don't match, just exactly how bad is it to use the first of the following 2 query statement syntax styles:

```
SELECT {COLUMN LIST}
FROM TABLE1 t1, TABLE2 t2, TABLE3 t3, TABLE4 t4 (etc)
WHERE t1.uid = t2.foreignid
AND t2.uid = t3.foreignid
AND t3.uid = t4.foreignid
etc
```

instead of

```
SELECT {COLUMN LIST}
FROM TABLE1 t1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t1.uid = t2.foreignid
INNER JOIN TABLE3 t3 ON t2.uid = t3.foreignid
INNER JOIN TABLE4 t4 ON t3.uid = t4.foreignid
```

I'm not sure if this is limited to microsoft SQL, or even a particular version, but my understanding is that the first scenario does a *full outer join* to make all possible correlations accessible.

I've used the first approach in the past to optimise queries that access two significantly large stores of data that each have peripheral table joined to them, with the product of those joins coming together late in the query. By allowing each of the "larger" table to join to their respective lookup tables, and only combining a specific subset of each of the larger tables, I found that there were notable speed improvements over introducing the large tables to each other prior to specific filtering.

**Under normal (simple joins) circumstance, would it not be far better to use the second scenario**? I find it to be more easily readable and it seems like it'll be much faster.

Comment: I would not use to optimize either, there are ways to do what you described using derived tables for instance or by changing the join order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-versus-where-clause-any-difference)

Comment: gotcha. the link says it all.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the best way to answer this is to take a look at how the database handles the query internally. If you're on SQL Server, use Profiler to see how many reads etc. each query takes and the query plan to see what route is being taken through the data. Statistics, skewing etc. will also most likely play a role.

Answer (score 2):

The first query doesn't produce a full OUTER join (which is the union of both LEFT and RIGHT joins). Essentially unless there are some [internal] SQL parser - specific optimizations, both queries are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would never use the first syntax. It may be the same performancewise but it is harder to maintain and far more subject to accidental cross joins when things get complex. If you miss an ON condition, it will fail the syntax check , if you miss one of the WHERE conditions that is the equivalent of an ON condition, it will happily do a cross join.  It is also a syntax that is 17 years out of date for goodness sakes!

Further, the left and right join syntax in the old syntax are broken in SQL Server and do NOT always return the correct results (it can sometimes interpet the results as a corss join instead of an outerjoin) and they have been deprecated and will not be useable at all in the next version. If you need to change one of the queries to use an outer join, then you can be looikng at a major rewrite as it is especially bad to try to mix the two kinds of syntax.